# Multiple search-replace operations on a selection

Tags: substitute, macro

I have a `LaTeX` file with a bunch of commands of the form `\label{<word>}` where the `<word>` represents a string that contains special characters, namely `á é í ó ú ý ð þ æ ö`. I'm looking for a quick way to change the special characters into a corresponding ASCII character(s): `a e i o u y dh th ae oe`. To give an example, I want to change `\label{orðabók}` to `\label{ordhabok}`.

If I wanted just to change, for example, all þ's to th, I would visually select the word inside the `\label{}`, exit to normal mode and then use

```
:s/\%Vþ/th/ge
```

And I could give two such commands at the same time using `|`, e.g.

```
:s/\%Vþ/th/ge|s/\%Vð/dh/ge
```

I guess I could just string together all ten commands, but I was hoping for a more elegant way. In particular, I would like to not have to write the `\%V` and the `g` every time.

A follow-up question: I have to do this for every `\label{}` command in a very long file, and I plan to make a macro or commmand that automates it. My plan was to make a macro that searches for the next occurance of `\label{`, visually selects the word inside the `{}`, and performs the substitutions I described above. Then I would just count the `\label` commands and run the macro that many times. If I get help with the first question, then I know how to implement this. But is there another method that would be faster for a very long file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about ... a substitution inside another one, and all thrown in a loop? E.g.

```
function! s:replaceSpecialChars(name)
    let from = ['á','é','í','ó','ú','ý','ð','þ','æ','ö']
    let to = ['a','e','i','o','u','y','dh','th','ae','oe']

    let i = 0
    while i < len(from)
        exe '%s/' . a:name . '{\zs.\{-}\ze}/\=substitute(submatch(0),from[i], to[i], "g")/g'
        let i += 1
    endwhile
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 ReplaceSpecialChars call s:replaceSpecialChars(<f-args>)
```

---

Copy the above code in a vim file, and `source` the file (e.g. `:w` and `so %` if it's the current file). Then you can run it when you are in your LaTeX buffer like this:

```
:ReplaceSpecialChars label
```

Just make sure to keep those lists (from, to) matched (equal nr. of elements).

This function globally replaces, in turn, any number of occurences of one of the characters from the `from[]` list to their `to[]` correspondent, but only for text found inside the `<name>{ }` construct.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work very well and is much more easily applied to similar situations than the mix of macros and registers that I had imagined.
I have one suggestion to generalize your solution:
Could the function take a string `name` as argument and then perform the substitutions inside `name{ }` instead of `label{ }`? Then I could call the function with argument `label` with the same effect as `:call ReplaceInLabels()`. How would I do that?

Comment: Yes, why not :) I edited the answer. I'll also probably add a command that takes a name as parameter (easier to use) - and ... done.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `:call ReplaceSpecialChars('label')` instead of `:ReplaceSpecialChars label`? The latter doesn't work for me.

Comment: I made it as a command, it's easier to run this way. It *should* work though, it just calls the original function with one argument. (I just retested it with a copy/paste on my machine and it runs alright)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. It works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Tim Pope's [abolish.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin provides a `:Subvert` (`:S` for short) command that lets you substitute a list of things for another list of things. For example, the following command will change `a` to `x`, `b` to `y`, and `c` to `z`:

```
:S/{a,b,c}/{x,y,z}/g
```

The plugin also provides a lot of other cool functionality that can't be easily articulated; I recommend checking it out.

Comment: Thanks, why reinvent the wheel? Note that these substitutions are not case-sensitive though.

Comment: It's not quite that it's not case sensitive, but that it also substitutes other case variants. For example, `:S/foo/bar/g` will convert `foo` to `bar`, `Foo` to `Bar`, and `FOO` to `BAR`. (It's good at matching case variants for multi-word terms as well.)

Comment: I was about to sit and write some utility for doing this... but, since tpope did it...

Answer (score 5):

How about that.

1. define your substitution dictionary:

   ```
   :let dict_subst = { 
        \ 'á': 'a', 
        \ 'é': 'e', 
        \ 'í': 'i', 
        \ 'ó': 'o', 
        \ 'ú': 'u', 
        \ 'ý': 'y', 
        \ 'ð': 'dh', 
        \ 'þ': 'th', 
        \ 'æ': 'ae', 
        \ 'ö': 'oe'}
   ```
2. Then call your substitution function like this:

   ```
   :exe ":s/".join(keys(dict_subst),'\|').'/\=dict_subst[submatch(0)]/g'
   ```

Comment: That's nicer than the 2 lists I used, but it ignores the "replace inside a label only" requirement.